# WordPress Favicon not Working For Images/Videos/PDFs

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, images, headers, icon

I am using WordPress with Neve theme, for my site, Favicon is working on posts/pages, but Favicons aren't visible for JPG/PNG/Videos.

If I use the Theme Customizer and select the Favicon PNG image, it shows on all posts and images etc.

But I want to have different Favicon Images on different URLs.

I saw that Theme was adding the below code on my site in Head.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/Icons/Icon72x72.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/Icons/Icon32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/Icons/Icon16x16.png">
```

this code was inserted `wp_head` to make it work.

It works perfectly on my posts and pages. For example the post [How Does Elon Musk Manage all his Companies Effectively?](https://milyin.com/how-does-elon-musk-manage-all-his-companies-effectively/) the favicon is visible perfectly.

But if I [Image from the save post](https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/How-Does-Elon-Musk-Manage-all-his-Companies-effectively.png) The Image shows favicon as WordPress logo instead of my site logo.

How to make it WordPress logo programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening media files only the file is loaded and not the html head of your file.

You can add a 'favicon.ico' file ('.png' may also work – not sure) to your root directory ('public_html/', 'www/' 'domain.com/' depending on server setup) and it should load even for media files as browsers are automaticly looking for an icon there.

Comment: Well, I know that html head is empty for Media files.... However how am I supposed to add the ion... What should be the name of file and where to place it?

Comment: The name should be 'favicon' and it should be in the 'root directory'. You can add it using ftp...

Comment: Confirmed that you'll need to upload "favicon.ico" to the web root, and that worked for me